# SELECT with a COUNT of another SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table in SQL that is a list of users checking in to a website. It looks much like this:

```
id | date | status 
------------------
```

Status can be 0 for not checking in, 1 for checked in, 2 for covered, and 3 for absent.

I'm trying to build one single query that lists all rows with `status = 0`, but also has a COUNT on how many rows have `status = 3` on each particular `id`.

Is this possible?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN`  the same table again, on id=id (assuming it's a userid and not a primary or unique key), status=3, and `COUNT` that second table.

Comment: have a small sample of the data and the result you'd like to see?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## MySQL VERSION

just join a count that is joined by id.

```
SELECT t.*, COALESCE(t1.status_3_count, 0) as status_3_count
FROM yourtable t
LEFT JOIN 
(   SELECT id, SUM(status=3) as status_3_count
    FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY id
) t1 ON t1.id = t.id
WHERE t.status = 0
```

note: this is doing the boolean sum (aka count)..
the expression returns either true or false a 1 or a 0. so I sum those up to return the count of status = 3 for each id

## SQL SERVER VERSION

```
SELECT id, SUM(CASE WHEN status = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as status_3_count
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY id
```

or just use a `WHERE status = 3` and a `COUNT(id)`

Comment: In SQL server, SUM(statuz=3) gives an error near =. Can u pls tell me what is the SQL server version for this ? Thanks.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev see my edit, I believe one of those two attempts will solve it

Answer (score 3):

Try a dependent subquery:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       (  SELECT count(*) 
          FROM sometable t2
          WHERE t2.id = t1.id 
            AND t2.status = 3
       ) As somecolumnname
FROM sometable t1
WHERE t1.status=0
```

Comment: dependent subqueries are much slower than just a regular join.. for every row in the table you are doing row^n comparisons... so like 1000 rows returns 1 million comparisons.

Comment: @JohnRuddell Yes, you are right, dependent subqueries on MySql are slow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a join for this. Write one query that will get all rows with a status zero:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE status = 0;
```

Then, write a subquery to get counts for the status of 3 for each id, by grouping by id:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM myTable
WHERE status = 3
GROUP BY id;
```

Since you want all the rows from the first table (at least that's what I am picturing), you can use a LEFT JOIN with the second table like this:

```
SELECT m.id, m.status, IFNULL(t.numStatus3, 0)
FROM myTable m
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS numStatus3
      FROM myTable
      WHERE status = 3
      GROUP BY id) t ON m.id = t.id
WHERE m.status = 0;
```

The above will only show the count for rows containing an id that has status 0. Hopefully this is what you are looking for. If it is not, please post some sample data and expected results and I will help you try to reach it. Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb8bee/3) example.